# To what points [esp+2Ch]?

Tags: windows, assembly, pe, esp

I am analyzing a Windows executable file(PE Format), probably written in Borland Delphi. The program starts with the following instructions:

```
    pusha                      (1)
    pushf                      (2)
    xor ebp, ebp
    jmp add_eh

add_eh:
    mov eax, ss:off_4025E5[ebp]
    mov dword ptr ss:(loc_402159+1)[ebp], eax
    push offset loc_40215f                (3)
    push dword ptr fs:0
    mov fs:0, esp                        (4)
    mov eax, [esp+2Ch]                    (5)
    cmp [eax+IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.e_magic], 'ZM'
    jnz short loc_40206C
```

I reproduced on paper the stack until the instruction marked with (5), it seems that at (5) the esp+2Ch is pointing above the first register(AX) pushed by (1).

Where does esp+2Ch point and what can be it's value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the corrected sequence that instruction **fetches the dword** prior to all the pushes

```
pusha pushes 8 general purpose register  = 0x20   = 0x20
pushf pushes 1 flag register             = 0x04   = 0x24
```

ebp is 0
mov eax, is/can/maybe junk anyway doesn't alter the stack
the next instuction also doesnt alter the stack

```
the next 2 pushes alter the stack        = 0x08   = 0x2c
```

the next instruction sets the seh handler

so it fetches the DWORD from the stack prior to pusha

if this was starting of a call this DWORD could be return address of the call    it can be from a earlier push instruction or moved to stack prior to pusha

just to clarify i assembled the instuction in place somewhere in ollydbg and traced through it see the output below

```
main    ntdll.76E96F51  NOP
main    ntdll.76E96F52  NOP
main    ntdll.76E96F53  NOP
main    ntdll.76E96F54  NOP
main    ntdll.76E96F55  PUSH    0BA0000 [0020F99C]=00000000 ESP=0020F99C
main    ntdll.76E96F5A  PUSHAD      ESP=0020F97C
main    ntdll.76E96F5B  PUSHFD  [0020F978]=76E212AD ESP=0020F978
main    ntdll.76E96F5C  XOR     EBP, EBP
main    ntdll.76E96F5E  MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+calc.0BA25E5]    [00BA25E5]=0F087E3B EAX=0F087E3B
main    ntdll.76E96F64  MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+calc.ULongAdd], EAX   [00BA215A]=0F087E3B
main    ntdll.76E96F6A  PUSH    0BA215F [0020F974]=0020F9F4 ESP=0020F974
main    ntdll.76E96F6F  PUSH    DWORD PTR FS:[0]    [7FFDF000]=0020F9A0 ESP=0020F970
main    ntdll.76E96F76  MOV     DWORD PTR FS:[0], ESP   [7FFDF000]=0020F9A0
main    ntdll.76E96F7D  MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+2C]  [0020F99C]=00BA0000 EAX=00BA0000
```

Comment: Unless the op messed up some instructions (however it seems he did, looking at that strange push referencing `fs`), the [esp+2C] isn't in `fs`. Without actually calculating offsets, i'd have assumed this restores `eax` which gets smashed a few instructions earlier. In cases like this, it's much easier to single-step a debugger a few times than trying to figure out manually.

Comment: I have added two new instructions that possibly make it easier to understand the ASM snippet.

Comment: Added the correct sequence of instructions, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @ner0x652  edited my answer  you need to know what was on the stack prior to pusha to know what will be in eax after all these instruction